# Apache camel processing two csv files simultaneously

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am trying to process two `.csv` files and to persist their data to the database.
I am using java dsl and not springs for the same.

**To explain the scenario a bit better :**
I am reading two `.csv` files and processing them to upload their data in the sql database.The steps I performed for this are

1. Specify the engine initialiser in the servlet container file.
2. Create an `EngineInitialiser`
3. Bind the EngineInitialiser to the core Engine.
4. Create the dao files required to persist the data to the database.
5. Create the engine module which defines the bindings.
6. Define the files which define the format specific for the files.

However, the problem is

There is a problem when trying to unmarshal the exchange to a `BindyCsvDataFormat`. There are two format class files as I have specified one for the file1 input file and one for the `file2.csv`.

Now bindy is  trying to map the format to the parent class file .However, when it picks up the `file1.csv` it maps it to both the model1 and model2 defined under the same package.
However, it should map it to only one class .How do I force it to map to only one format class?
**The error is as follows:**

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Some fields are missing (optional or mandatory), line: 1
>   at org.apache.camel.dataformat.bindy.BindyCsvFactory.bind(BindyCsvFactory.java:215)
>   atorg.apache.camel.dataformat.bindy.csv.BindyCsvDataFormat.unmarshal(BindyCsvDataFormat.java:169)atorg.apache.camel.processor.UnmarshalProcessor.process(UnmarshalProcessor.java:58)
>   at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
>       at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)
>       at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:71)at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)
>   at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:91)
>       at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.processErrorHandler(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:333)
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:223)
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:45)
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.DefaultChannel.process(DefaultChannel.java:304)
>       at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:117)
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:45)
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.processAsync(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:150)
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.process(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:117)
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteInflightRepositoryProcessor.processNext(RouteInflightRepositoryProcessor.java:50)
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)
>       at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)
>       at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:71)
>       at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processExchange(GenericFileConsumer.java:352)
>       at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processBatch(GenericFileConsumer.java:175)
>       at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:136)
>       at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:138)
>       at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:90)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:181)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:205)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
>   |#]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use different package names for different bindy models. Thats a limitation currently, and will be improved in the future.

Comment: Hi Claus,After using two different packages as well bindy is trying to map a single file to both the models though they are specified in different packages and thus, is giving the same error.

Comment: Your bindy annotations and the actual CSV file does not match up.

Comment: One of the file is getting processed neatly however ,when the second csv file is being processed in the factory.bind() method where the file's csv data has to be bound with the model classes, bindy is binding it with both the models model1 and model2 though it should map  it to only one.This is happening as the model object of the BindyCsvDataformat has both the models stored in it .So while processing the second file it is asking for 4 parameters that is 2 parameters from each model model1 and model2.

Comment: Make sure you separate your model classes completely in different packages. And use 2 different bindy to parse each of those models

Comment: Yes they are seperated into two different packages and there are two different bindy's which are processing both the models.However, it is difficult to figure out as to why the second file is mapped to two models when it should be mapped to only one as clearly specified in the route.Is there a threading issue here should I use two different threads to implement this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Different entity managers should solve the problem.