# Apache camel reading two .csv files simultaneously

Tags: java, apache-camel

By changing the packages of the two domain models solved the above error which I had posted in my earlier link 
[Apache camel processing two csv files simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943445/apache-camel-processing-two-csv-files-simultaneously).

However, it is giving another error and rolling back the processing of the two .csv files.
Both the .csv files have two seperate processors for processing the exchanges.

> ERROR:
>   [#|2012-06-12T10:23:54.651+1000|SEVERE|glassfish3.0.1|org.apache.camel.processor.DefaultErrorHandler|_ThreadID=35;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-GEPC7848-52123-1339460612530-0-651 on ExchangeId: ID-GEPC7848-52123-1339460612530-0-658). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Caught: java.lang.NullPointerException.

I would debug this and step through the processors to see what's wrong. Of Course, it could be something else. Do you have any threading dependencies? Shared variables? Could you post code?

Comment: I debugged the issue. The problem is that when the second file is getting processed in the bind(List<String> tokens, Map<String, Object> model, int line) method in BindyCsvFactory.java class the model map has both the models model1 and model2 so when the second file is getting processing in the code line field.set(modelField, value) it is setting it to both the models instead of only one.However, the field should map to only one data format model as per the code.How do I fix this?

Comment: The problem is that there is a single thread handling two files so it is causing problems.I will seperate it out into two different threads and hopefully that would work.Because for BindyCsvDataFormat the methods should be executed in a synchronized manner as any other dataformat class is to be executed.

Comment: As told you on the other ticket, use 2 different bindy data formats, so there are 2 instances of BindyCsvFactory

Comment: I solved the issue.Thank you Claus.The problem was Bindy was not identifying the package names properly.I had named the packages domainpackage1 and domain.Bindy was  binding the file to both the models which were defined seperately in these two different packages as, it could not distinguish the package names.I changed the name of the packages and now it works.Thank you for your support and help.

Answer (score 0):

A Nullpointer Exception is always a good candidate for a bug. Can you try this with DEBUG logging and check if you get a complete stack trace? It would be great if you could create a jira issue for this with the stacktrace and description how to reproduce in the camel jira.